# Arduino IDE: Is there an Alternative Interface for working with .ino sketches and binaries?

Tags: python, java, c, node.js, qt

Recently, I learned that the Arduino IDE (or at least version 2), downloadable from the main Arduino CC site, is built using Electron and Node. That's a discovery about which I'm not at all happy. (Eww, Google tech stack in a supposedly open-source project!) Given that the IDE is basically a GUI to/wrapper around a text editor that highlights C/C++ syntax (such as `vim` or `emacs`), `gcc`, `avrdude` and a serial terminal (such as `kitty` or `smartty`), it should be possible to either replace it with these individual applications *or* build a frontend interface (using `subprocess` or similar) in a different language with a different framework/toolkit (such as C/C++, C#, Nim, Python or vimScript, possibly with Gtk+, Qt 5/Pyside 2/Otherside, `charva`, `ConsoleDraw`, `ncurses`, pdcurses-Mod, `notcurses` or `urwid`). At least the Arduino IDE is open-source, so it's possible to look at/through the code and convert it to something else or write something compatible.

To that end, I searched the 'Net for an alternate tech stack for an Arduino IDE (because surely I'm not the only person to have this idea). However, the only thing I've found is "ArduinoIDE-PyQT" on GitHub, a project with the last commit dated around fourteen years ago. As far as I can tell from a brief look at it, it's "in a pre-alpha state" according to `README.MD`, uses Qt 4 and Scintilla (woot!), has no releases and looks very much like a skeleton that the developer(s) abandoned after losing inspiration. (Apparently, he/they is/are contactable in the #Arduino channel on irc.freenode.com, so I'm trying my luck by reaching out there, in the hope of getting some clarification.)

If my assumptions/suspicions are correct, I am prepared to further investigate and fork the ArduinoIDE-PyQT project to continue its development. Alternately, I'll see if I can make headway going the CLI route (including using the Arduino CLI software), then build something TUI-based (because I like TUIs). Finding, listing and installing Arduino libraries through it might prove to be one of the more difficult aspects (although I'm hoping that looking at the IDE's code and writing an equivalent using `urllib3` and/or `requests` in Python/Cython proves otherwise).

My question is thus this: Does anybody know of (and recommend) a usable and working alternative to the electron-and-Node-based Arduino IDE GUI (even if it's a bundle of shell/Python scripts for the components with which it interacts)?